# Error: no main manifest attribute, in ---.war file

Tags: jakarta-ee, war, manifest, putty

I have a Java EE application that uses JPA. I have deployed it successfully via putty, but when I try to run it to persist something to the database with the command:

```
   java -jar /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/docroot/cabosand_crm.war
```

I get an error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/docroot/cabosand_crm.war
```

Comment: If you get "an error" at runtime, then you have a stack trace. Post it

Comment: In fact the project doesn't run, once I taped the first command to run project i get the error posted

Comment: which comes from somewhere ... and which certainly isn't the JPA API

Comment: From my search I discovered that I need to add main Class handling in the manifest file, but in my case I don t have a main application its JEE app